# grid-template - why does this not fit into a single row?

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]Have got three items. Why would they not fit a in a single row with three columns

```css
    #grid {
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: grid;
      grid-template: 
        "a a a" 100px
    }
    #grid > div {
      background-color: red;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: it runs as expected on SO built-in js/css/html environment.
It runs unexpectedly on both jsfiddle and codepen.

https://jsfiddle.net/97grq2pz/186/
https://codepen.io/matcheek/pen/EOgmzr
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template

Comment: Just checking whether css grid is mature enough to replace flexbox.

Comment: you have invisible character before and after divs considered as grid element ... remove them

Comment: @JakubMuda you shouldn't make comments that are off-base, opinionated, and frankly not true depending on who you are and what you are doing.